# Check if Array contains true in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to limit failed login attempts per `ip`.

I have the following:

```
  def validate(email, context)
    attempt = insert_into_attempts(email, context)
    return nil unless allow_login_by_ip(context.ip_address)
    flag_successful_attempt(attempt, context.ip_address)
    load_data
  end

  def allow_login_by_ip(ip_address)
    limit = LoginLimits.new(ip_address).limit
    last_5_attempts = AuthenticationAttempt.select("id","successful").where(ip: ip_address).last(5)
    last_5_attempts.include?("true")
  end 

  def insert_into_attempts(email, context)
    attempt = AuthenticationAttempt.new(
      :email => email,
      :ip => context.ip_address)
    attempt.save
  end 

  def flag_successful_attempt(attempt, ip_address)
    AuthenticationAttempt.where(ip: ip_address).last.update(successful: '1')
  end
```

The issue I am having is that it always returns `fasle`. I must be searching the `array` incorrectly but I am not sure why. `last_5_attempts` is:

```
#<AuthenticationAttempt id: 1, successful: false>, 
#<AuthenticationAttempt id: 2, successful: false>, 
#<AuthenticationAttempt id: 3, successful: true>,
#<AuthenticationAttempt id: 4, successful: false>, 
#<AuthenticationAttempt id: 5, successful: false>]
```

Comment: You might want to consider the [`rack-attack`](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) gem instead of implementing this feature by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean `true`, then you mean:

```
last_5_attempts.include?(true)
```

Because:

```
true == "true"
# => false
```

Yet that's not quite enough, as you're asking if an array of `[id, successful]` values has any entry that is *literally* just `true`, (`[1,true] != true`) so you want:

```
last_5_attempts.any? |id, successful|
  successful
end
```

You could also omit `id` from your column fetch since you don't use it and instead:

```
AuthenticationAttempt.where(ip: ip_address).pluck(:successful).last(5).any?
```

Where `pluck` with a single argument returns a "flat" array instead of an array of arrays.

To check for at least one successful login in the last 5 or no login history:

```
attempts = AuthenticationAttempt.where(ip: ip_address)
!attempts.any? or attempts.pluck(:successful).last(5).any?
```

Comment: `AuthenticationAttempt.where(ip: ip_address).pluck(:successful).last(5).any?` makes everything cleaner and easier. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to add a condition where it would return true in case `ip` does not exist or just doesn't have 5 tries yet? I am asking because I am trying to figure out how to deal with new customers but failing to come up with an addition to the method.

Comment: That's a little more complicated but I've added an example there.

Comment: I am also allowing users to log in if they have under 5 attempts so I added size to it `!attempts.any? or attempts.size < 5 or attempts.pluck(:successful).last(5).any?`. I guess the `any?` is not relevant anymore because I am checking size?

Comment: Sure. You could go with either none or less than 5, as zero is less than five.

Answer (score 1):

```
AuthenticationAttempt.where(ip: ip_address).last(5).exists?(successful: true)
```

```
AuthenticationAttempt.where(ip: ip_address).order(id: :desc).limit(5).exists?(successful: true)
```

You can use [ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#exists?](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) to check for a successful attempt without retrieving any data or instantiating any records.

**Update**: We need to use `.order(id: :desc).limit(5)` in place of `.last(5)` to ensure we have an [ActiveRecord::Relation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb) instance to call `exists?` on.

**Update 2**: `exists?` replaces any `limit` given with `limit(1)`

```
AuthenticationAttempt.limit(5).exists?
=> SELECT 1 AS one FROM "authentication_attempts" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Therefore we need to wrap the subquery in an outer existence query:

```
AuthenticationAttempt.exists?(AuthenticationAttempt.limit(5))
=> SELECT  1 AS one FROM "authentication_attmepts" WHERE "authentication_attmepts"."id" IN (SELECT  "authentication_attmepts"."id" FROM "authentication_attmepts" LIMIT $1) LIMIT $2  [["LIMIT", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

This is a slightly more complex query, but still has the performance benefits of not loading anything from the database.  The inner subquery gives us our last 5 attempts, and the outer query checks for the existence of a successful attempt:

```
 AuthenticationAttempt
   .where(successful: true)
   .exists?(AuthenticationAttempt.where(ip: ip_address).order(id: :desc).limit(5))
```

Comment: I am not sure I can run `exists?` on an Array? It gives an error `undefined method 'exists?' for []:Array`.

Comment: @A.J Try `order(id: :desc).limit(5)` instead of `last(5)`. I thought `#last` returned an Association, but it looks like I am wrong and it is returning an  Array. Let me know if that works and I will update my answer.

Comment: @A.J I updated the query.  `exists?` will overwrite any limits, so you need to structure the query to create a subquery of the correct records and then do the existence check on them.

Answer (score 1):

try

```rb
last_5_attempts.map(&:to_s).include?("true")
```

instead of

```rb
last_5_attempts.include?("true")
```